# How can I play a HTML5 or Flash video with keyboard shortcuts on a system without a mouse?

Tags: firefox, keyboard, accessibility

## Original Question

The Firefox [help pages state](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/viewing-html5-audio-and-video):

> After you click on the media on a web page, to give it focus, you can control the playback with your keyboard.

But how can we initially give it focus if we are not using a mouse

## Edits

Since I cannot provide a link to the video page, here is the relevant page source:

```
<div class="my-account">
    <p class="back-link">
        <a href="https://shop.dananddave.com/streaming/customer/products/">
            <small>&laquo;</small>Back to My Streaming Videos</a>
    </p>
    <div class="page-title">
         <h1>The Unreal Work, vol. 1 - <span id="streaming-link-titile">PaulWilson</span></h1>
    </div>
    <div id="my-streaming-product">
        <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/55133774?show_title=1&amp;show_byline=0&amp;show_portrait=0&amp;color=000000&amp;fullscreen=1&amp;autoplay=0" height="100%" width="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons-set">
        <p class="back-link">
            <a href="https://shop.dananddave.com/streaming/customer/products/">
                <small>&laquo;</small>Back to My Streaming Videos</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the [`video` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-video-element) has the [`controls` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#attr-media-controls) (i.e., Firefox shall use its own control menu), you can use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to focus the video player. When it has focus, you can use the keyboard controls.

If the `video` element doesn’t have the `controls` attribute, it’s the author’s responsibility to provide a control menu – and then you’d have to hope that the author had keyboard accessibility in mind.

However, for such a video it might work to focus the player (with <kbd>Tab</kbd>) and open the context menu (for example, via <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>), where you can enable the default controls. After this, it should be possible to use the default keyboard controls. *(I couldn’t test it with many videos, so it might depend on the author’s script.)*

Comment: I tried all of those methods, and for this particular video, I wasn't able to obtain focus. I ended up using the JavaScript console of Firefox to call the `.focus()` event on the darn thing.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin: Could you provide a link to this video?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot provide a link, because it's a secure video served within a protected user account. I can tell you, though, that the video is within a Vimeo embed.

Comment: I added relevant page source in lieu of a link to the video.

Answer (score 0):

press <kbd>Tab</kbd> repeatedly until the video is focused then press <kbd>context menu</kbd> (looks like a box with three lines) to get controls like <kbd>play</kbd> and <kbd>pause</kbd> or use the keyboard shortcuts provided by firefox

Comment: I have not be able to obtain focus on the element with `tab`.